# Autoclose and Autoindent Conflict in Vim

Tags: c, vim, editor, vi

So I'm using a tool to automatically indent after brackets in C files:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

However, I also want to automatically close brackets, parens, and other code delimiters when I type the first part of them. To achieve this, I have added this to my vimrc:

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
```

Now, however, when I press enter in between the two brackets that are created, my code is no longer automatically indented. If the automatic completion of brackets feature is disabled, it works fine, but I have to manually close my brackets. I have also tried using DelimiterMate to the same effect. Is there any way around this?

Comment: There is an AutoPairs plugin for vim for this purpose: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599

Comment: DelimitMate does that very well. Did you read the doc? There are a bunch of options like `let delimitMate_expand_cr = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) contains a full discussion of the topic, starting with simple mappings like yours. Because there are many corner cases and areas where it should *just work*, I recommend a plugin though. The mentioned page has a comprehensive list of plugins. (I occasionally use *AutoClose* by Karl Guertin.)